# How can I use the response from a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

This is the first time I have used a confirm box and I'd like some advice on how to use it please, I want to use the users input of "Yes or No" but not sure how to do it? If I wanted to reference the input from the JOptionPane in an if statement how would go about it?

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Click yes to terminate. ", "TERMINATE SIMULATION?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it like:

```
   int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Click yes to terminate. ", "TERMINATE SIMULATION?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == result) {
                System.out.println("yes");
     } else if (JOptionPane.NO_OPTION == result) {
                System.out.println("No");
     }else{
            System.out.println("Nothing");
    }
```

Also find the option types and return values below(from source):

```
 /**
     * Type meaning Look and Feel should not supply any options -- only
     * use the options from the <code>JOptionPane</code>.
     */
    public static final int         DEFAULT_OPTION = -1;
    /** Type used for <code>showConfirmDialog</code>. */
    public static final int         YES_NO_OPTION = 0;
    /** Type used for <code>showConfirmDialog</code>. */
    public static final int         YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION = 1;
    /** Type used for <code>showConfirmDialog</code>. */
    public static final int         OK_CANCEL_OPTION = 2;

    //
    // Return values.
    //
    /** Return value from class method if YES is chosen. */
    public static final int         YES_OPTION = 0;
    /** Return value from class method if NO is chosen. */
    public static final int         NO_OPTION = 1;
    /** Return value from class method if CANCEL is chosen. */
    public static final int         CANCEL_OPTION = 2;
    /** Return value form class method if OK is chosen. */
    public static final int         OK_OPTION = 0;
    /** Return value from class method if user closes window without selecting
     * anything, more than likely this should be treated as either a
     * <code>CANCEL_OPTION</code> or <code>NO_OPTION</code>. */
    public static final int         CLOSED_OPTION = -1;
```

Also, don't do int check directly for response value, like `if(1==result)` for `NO_OPTION`, always use constants from the `JoptionPane` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more about Swing Dialog then please have a look at the below section of *Swing Tutorial* where it is explained in detail along with a lot examples.

- [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
- [Creating and Showing Simple Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create)